# Installed WCF service with Installshield generated setup Error

Tags: vb.net, wcf, iis, installshield

I've just generated the installer for a WCF Service and I'm trying to use: 
The structure installed at the wwwroot is the following:
http://bit.ly/11zZ85E

In the bin folder are included all dlls in which the service depends. The class that implements the service contract is defined in one of those dll. All generation and instalation proccess is all good. And I have on the IIS Manager the following:

http://bit.ly/10xBI3Y

The issue is that when I try to access the wsdl at the browser I'm only able to see:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="VB" Debug="true" Service="MyApplication.ServiceImplementation.LicensingService" CodeBehind="MyApplication.ServiceImplementation.Service.vb" %>
```

And If I try to use the Add Service Reference from a Visual Studio project I see this:

*There was an error downloading

    (ServiceAddress)/$metadata
The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 
    (ServiceAddress)
The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed.
The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.*

The installer I did was generated with Installshield 2010.

Here is my Web.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
<compilation strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
<service name="MyApp.ServiceImplementation.Service" behaviorConfiguration="WSSecurityBehavior">
<!-- Service Endpoints -->
<!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
<endpoint address="Operations" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="MyApp.ServiceContracts.IService" />
<endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" name="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
</service>
</services>
<behaviors>
<serviceBehaviors>
<behavior name="WSSecurityBehavior">
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
</behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
<wsHttpBinding>
<binding name="WSSecurityBinding">
<reliableSession enabled="true" ordered="true" />
</binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<!--protocolMapping>
<add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
</protocolMapping-->
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
<directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
<handlers accessPolicy="Read, Script" />
<defaultDocument>
<files>
<clear />
<add value="Service.svc" />
</files>
</defaultDocument>
<httpErrors>
<clear />
</httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```